# How do I modify Cmder to show my Git change summary on the prompt? (+A/~C/-D)

Tags: git, conemu, cmder, clink

I can see the output of the branch name no problem (although, in version 1.3.4+ it also strangely outputs "master -> origin" when it didn't use to), but I can't figure out why it has never successfully shown changes. This works in Powershell+Poshgit under Cmder, and looking at the \vendor\clink.lua script it seems like this is where the changes would go.

Comment: <branch name> +1 ~2 0 , similar to https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw3mJ.png

Comment: GitShow branch can be found in: <Cmder_Home>\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\GitShowBranch.cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the gist for changing Clink git prompt here: https://gist.github.com/jonasem/e8b3a6258a495946df12

If you replace the matching functions with the git_prompt_filter and get_git_status within, it will then display. For convenience, I've made a gist for dropping into "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\" (as the one in vendor gets replaced every install of cmder, per the instructions in the file):
https://gist.github.com/mattdkerr/23db4db40c276b1481b01b0fa26de009

You will need to delete or edit %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\clink.lua and comment out the set filter commands (double hyphen, or '--', is comment line prefix).

Comment: worked without modifying %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\clink.lua . Not sure why.
I did find out that the mentioned "comment out set filter commands" means comment out the line: "clink.prompt.register_filter(git_prompt_filter, 50)"